# weird behavior on mysql order by id desc

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have some trouble while using mysql.

I do a standard request like I often do, and to this time there was no problem.

I'm trying to sort a request by Id desc, and it does not work.

Below is the request :

```
SELECT `spb_breadcrumb_id` ,
       `spb_breadcrumb_id_breadcrumb` ,
       `spb_breadcrumb_base_url` ,
       `spb_breadcrumb_label` ,
       `spb_breadcrumb_link`
FROM `spb_breadcrumb`
WHERE `spb_breadcrumb_base_url` = 'index.php?p=maisons-en-bois&module=exemples_realisations'
ORDER BY `spb_breadcrumb_id_breadcrumb` DESC
```

and below is the result, as you can see, the result is not ordered as expected, it should display 255, 256 and 257.

But now it display 256, then 257, then 255... all is wrong.

I do have an index on the id.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

below the showing of mysql :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note** You are using `ORDER BY` on wrong column

Because you are using `ORDER BY` on this column `spb_breadcrumb_id_breadcrumb` , This column has three value and they all are 76,76,76.

Use it on this column which you want to order, which should be this according to the picture

`spb_breadcrumb_id` this column has three value `256,257 and 255`

so change your this line like this

```
ORDER BY `spb_breadcrumb_id` DESC
```

Comment: thank you, I did not notice that before, because, for all pages it worked fine. Now the problem is solved. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 5):

You made mistake As Arif_suhail_123 said...

if you want `speb_breadcrumb_id`  in this order `255, 256, 257` ... then change query

```
ORDER BY `spb_breadcrumb_id` ASC
```